# Cannot Change Forms or ASP.NET at the LocalHost Level with PS using Set-WebConfiguration system.web

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a PS Script to update or change the root level of IIS Authentication with settings for Forms Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation. I am able to change Anonymous and Windows Authentication but I am having no luck with ASP.NET and Forms. I can change the ASP.NET and Form settings under the Default Site Web directory but not at the localhost level. This is what I am trying but it does not work:

Forms Authentication

```
Set-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication 'IIS:\' -value @{mode='Forms'}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of error message, if any, do you get?

Comment: Funny thing is I get no message. It looks like it runs. But in IIS it does not change.